# Change store name of merchant center via php api

Tags: google-shopping-api

Is there a way to change the store name of a merchant center id via the php Google shopping api?

In the doc, I can't find any obvious way to do that. What keyword do I have to search for?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but that facility is not avalible within the API maily for security reasons as would require revalidation of the store